# How to access python packages(pyside) installed by homebrew in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pyside6

I am trying to access python packages installed by homebrew  in pycharm, I tried calling the pyside package in my virtual environment but doesn't seem to find the package. I installed the package using "brew install" but I do not seem to have access to the package